# Instaling Modules using pip

Tags: python, pip

I m trying to install python modules using pip but getting the following error

i tried installing it using anaconda prompt and was succesful and was able to use in jupyter notebook but i could not use that in python

have even upgraded python and pip

i am using python version 3.7.2

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
C:\Program Files\Python>pip install pytube
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in
 Python is not available.
Collecting pytube
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")': /simple/pytube/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")': /simple/pytube/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")': /simple/pytube/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")': /simple/pytube/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")': /simple/pytube/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pytube/: There was a problem confi
rming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max r
etries exceeded with url: /simple/pytube/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to
HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytube (from versions:
 )
No matching distribution found for pytube
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in
 Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming
 the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retrie
s exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS UR
L because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: what is the version of python you use? you can get it buy python --version.

Comment: Installation from PyPi requires SSL. So, better upgrade pip or upgrade python version. That might work.

Comment: I have tried the mentioned upgrading step and my python version is 3.7.2

Comment: Please if you could all sort this ... I have a project to build

Comment: Installation of openSSL from this link can also fix. https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: Ok I will try and let you know

Comment: installed openssl then again gave pip install pytube command same error still